# Camel REST DSL API - Multiple Content Type - XML Error

Tags: java, json, xml, apache-camel

I am trying to create a Camel REST service via Java DSL that can consume/produce both json and xml and the JSON works but I receive the an error when I try to retrieve the result in XML.

RestMethods Class:

public class RestMethods extends RouteBuilder {

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    rest()
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json_xml)
            .consumes("application/json, application/xml")
            .produces("application/json, application/xml")
            .get("/rating")
            .toD("direct:getRatingByClient");
}
```

Route Implementation:

```
public class GetRatingByClientRoute extends RouteBuilder{

// Use to created the mock
private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("direct:getRatingByClient")

    // Request
    .to("log:init")

    // Mediation
    .process(exchange -> {

        // TODO Implement route
        TestEntity test = new TestEntity();
        test.setTestAttribute("Teste");
        exchange.getOut().setBody(test);

    // Response
    .to("log:end");

}

}
```

When I run with Content-Type application/json works like a charm.
But, when i run with Content-Type application/xml i got this error:
***java.io.IOException: org.apache.camel.InvalidPayloadException: No body available of type: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement but has value: class GetRatingByClientRouteResponse***

Follow the requisition that I´m testing:
curl -X GET \
  'http://localhost:8080/credits/v1/rating?client_cpf_cnpj=11111111111' \
  -H 'Accept: application/xml' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/xml'

Comment: Not sure I follow but your GetRatingByClientRoute class only returns a json. Where does it return a xml message?

Comment: I updated the example to be more clear. I´m trying to build a REST API with multiple Content Types using the Apache Camel REST DSL. But when i use the application/xml Contenty Type I got the error InvalidPayloadException.

Comment: Don't use exchange.getOut() use exchange.getIn().setBody(...)

Comment: I tryed rigth now with getIn and the problem remains!

Comment: Please do log before you set the exchange to ensure you are returning a valid xml.

Comment: Ok but are you actually returning valid xml message?

Comment: Yep, it´s a valid XML. See the log: 14:25:45.446 [qtp327986890-19] INFO end - Exchange[ExchangePattern: InOut, BodyType: com.test.api.entities.TestEntity, Body: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<testEntity>
    <test_attribute>Teste</test_attribute>
</testEntity>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164282/discussion-between-rafael-manzoni-and-souciance-eqdam-rashti).

Answer (score 0):

I´ve open a bug for camel and the response worked:

eed to use jaxb.index files for your JAXB classes. Or you can turn off the data format to require a JAXBElement by

```
.dataFormatProperty("mustBeJAXBElement", "false");
```

This configuration goes on the RestConfiguration DSL, like this:

```
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration()
            .component("servlet")
            .contextPath("/credits/v1")
            .enableCORS(true)
            .apiContextPath("/api-doc")
            .apiProperty("api.title", "REST API")
            .apiProperty("api.version", "v1")
            .apiContextRouteId("doc-api")
            .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto)
            .dataFormatProperty("prettyPrint", "true")
            .dataFormatProperty("mustBeJAXBElement", "false");

    }
```

For more information check this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-12217